# Transforming and drawing isometric textures

Tags: java, 3d, drawing, textures, isometric

I'm planning to make a game and doing some research.
One of the features will be an isometric third-person view, which should be able to be rotated freely over 360 degrees.
This rules out the use of a simple tileset, because I cannot rotate tiles.
I therefore want to transform a texture and draw it on the screen that way, preferably even multiple textures (sides of a block). However, I could not find anything to help me with this.

TL;DR 
How do I transform textures the way I need to to form isometric tiles which can rotate a full 360 degrees? I also need some kind of formula that stays correct even if I turn less or more than 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Graphics2D -- you can cast most Graphics references to Graphics2D, and use this more powerful API.

In particular you have the `rotate()` and `transform()` methods.

See:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html

Comment: This does seem to be what I need. Do you use this more often? Because I've been looking at it and I wonder whether `public abstract boolean drawImage(Image img, AffineTransform xform, ImageObserver obs)` is the function I need. If so, it is not very clear what the Observer is notified of and what it should do, if anything.